# Jenkins - Run job if other multiple jobs are successful

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

How can I start a job if all 3 other jobs are successful?

Here is the scenario:

```
job1 - build module 1
job2 - build module 2
job3 - build module 3
job4 - main program
```

Run job4 (main program) if all modules build are successful (Job 1,2 and 3) so the main program can checkout all 3 modules from 3 different github repo and build the main program.

How can it be chained so its automatic?

Answer (score 2):

Start with job4.  Have job4 schedule builds of job1, job2, and job3 and wait for them to finish.  Then, if all 3 scheduled builds succeed, job4 may continue.